# TEXTJOIN cells unless a cell contain part of a string

Tags: google-sheets

I have several tables that represent rooms in our office, each table includes a column of few cells contain workers names and a device named like  the following "Device A", "device B" etc.

Table 1:

| HR G1:G6 |
| --- |
| George |
| Ema |
| Benjamin |
| Johanna |
| Device A |

Table 2:

| Dev H1:H6 |
| --- |
| Josh |
| Jenna |
| Tom |
| Jessica |
| Device B |

I want to summarize all their names exclude the device to a cell on a new table.

Table 3:

| Room | NAME A1:B3 |
| --- | --- |
| HR | George, Ema, Benjamin, Johanna |
| Dev | Josh, Jenna, Tom, Jessica |

The issue is that I can change the devices order so the names on the table can change often.

I want to use TEXTJOIN (or other tool) to combine all cells unless the cell includes "Device" in it, without specify exactly which one.

I tried to use REGEXMATCH, VLOOKUP, SEARCH, COUNTIF but they all return a list, so its not working well inside TEXTJOIN.

I've tried to use FILTER too but wildcard doesn't work there so I must provide the full name of the device.

Please your advice,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Exactly as shown on the tables above.
I got names in a column (Table 1) and I want to copy all of them except of names started with "Device" to a separate cell (like in table 3)
For what I know, its not allowed to share pictures on this forum, unless I'm wrong.

Anyway I've edited the question with the names so it will be more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```
=textjoin(", ", 1, filter(G1:G6, not(regexmatch(G1:G6, "Device"))))
```

or

```
=textjoin(", ", 1, filter(G1:G6, left(G1:G6, 6) <> "Device"))
```

(Include the sheet name if you want the results to appear on a different tab).

Comment: First option works as expected! thanks!